# Is there any interactive graph visualization tool where I can have nodes and edges that are in an excel file?

Tags: python, graph, visualization, interactive

[I am aiming to have an interactive graph like one in image, where there are nodes from A-B, B-C etc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyqAr.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can start off with packages like networkx and graphviz